# How to shift data in only one column up and down in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

| ID | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |

And I am trying to shift ONLY the values in the "Count" column down one so that it looks as follows:

| ID | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NA |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 0 |

I will also need to eventually shift the same data up one:

| ID | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | NA |

I've tried the following code:

```
shift <- function(x, n){
        c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n))
        }
      
      df$Count <- shift(df$Count, 1)
```

But it ended up duplicating the titles and shifting the data down, like as follows:

| ID | Count |
| --- | --- |
| ID | Count |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 |

Is there an easy way for me to accomplish this? Thank you!!

Comment: Use `dplyr::lag` or `data.table::shift`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# set as data.table
setDT(df)

# shift
df[, count := shift(count, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df$Count=c(NA, df$Count[1:(nrow(df)-1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) dplyr** Using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, use lag and lead from dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% mutate(CountLag = lag(Count), CountLead = lead(Count))
##   ID Count CountLag CountLead
## 1  1     3       NA         5
## 2  2     5        3         2
## 3  3     2        5         0
## 4  4     0        2         1
## 5  5     1        0        NA
```

**2) zoo**  This creates a zoo object using zoo's vectorized lag.  Optionally use fortify.zoo(z) or as.ts(z) to convert it back to a data frame or ts object.

Note that dplyr clobbers lag with its own lag so we used stats::lag to ensure it does not interfere.  The stats:: can optionally be omitted if dplyr is not loaded.

```
library(zoo)

z <- stats::lag(read.zoo(DF), seq(-1, 1)); z
  Index lag-1 lag0 lag1
1     1    NA    3    5
2     2     3    5    2
3     3     5    2    0
4     4     2    0    1
5     5     0    1   NA
```

**3) collapse**  flag from the collapse package is also vectorized over its second argument.

```
library(collapse)

with(DF, data.frame(ID, Count = flag(Count, seq(-1, 1))))
##   ID Count.F1 Count... Count.L1
## 1  1        5        3       NA
## 2  2        2        5        3
## 3  3        0        2        5
## 4  4        1        0        2
## 5  5       NA        1        0
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, Count = c(3, 5, 2, 0, 1))
```